# create WCF dns-router

Tags: wcf, service, dns, forward

I have a winforms application that is consuming a WCF service.  So far, the WCF service is a selfhosted service on the local pc.  It contains several interfaces (one per program functionallity).
As an improvement I want to expose the service to the internet, so I can call it using a new mobile app.  This can be easily done by configuring the router/firewall and use some kind of dynamic dns or remember the ip address (in worst case scenario).

But now, here comes the real question:
In a next step I will distribute the winforms app to several locations (call it customers), acompagnied with their local WCF service en their mobile app.  In order to allow the customer to connect to their wcf service (using the mobile app), I can set up now a dynamic dns for each customer, but I don't want to do that.  First of all, the best dyndns services are not free, or you have to renew periodically.  Second, I want to offer the customers my own dns service so I can 'forward' their wcf call to their own local service.
The wcfdnsrouter should be located at a public webhost, where the customers ip address is provided with an ip-updater (as it is often the case for other dyndns services)

As an example, imagine this:

Customer A; IP1; endpoint: http://wcfdnsrouter.com/A

Customer B; IP2; endpoint: http://wcfdnsrouter.com/B

Where I want that 
wcfdnsrouter.com/**A** will forward (or route?) ALL calls to **IP1** 
and
wcfdnsrouter.com/**B** will forward (or route?) ALL calls to **IP2**

With this scenario, the customer can access his service using mobile app from every place on earth.  Hardware configuration on customers site is not a problem.

The goal is to use a parameter, rather than having an other url per customer.  This should reduce the configuration and avoid duplicating my service.  However, it is still an open trace (in this case, I need to create a subdomain and copy the wcfdnsrouter that is nothing more than a ordinary routingservice).

So, the entry point seems to be a restfull service that routes the message to another ip address\service.
I did already some research about routingservices, but I think I'll not get where I want.  Contentbased routing is not an option since I don't want to change all my interfaces to have a criteria.  I do not see how to make the link between the parameter in the restfull service with the ip addres I need to call (so another service).

Security is not realy a issue at this moment.

Please note that is question is NOT about (free) dns services.  The purpose is to create it myself.  Activating a new customer should not be more than installing the auto-ip-updater and assigning some kind of code (like A and B) in the example.

I need some advice how to do that.  Maybe I'm on the wrong track thinking about routing?  Maybe there is a very easy way that I mis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do but have you looked at the built-in [WCF RoutingService capability?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd699773.aspx)

Comment: Yes I did, but found that routing is not what I want.  With Routing, I think the routing service should implement the same interface as the target service?  This is not the case.  In short: I want to create my own DDNS that forward ANY call of ANY (managed) service to a new endpoint (=IP address stored in database).  You can compare it with a DDNS for you website, but here it is for a WCF service.